# Regex to extract Credit Card information

Tags: regex

I have some data from which I only want to extract Card details i.e. Card number, Expr month/Year and Cvv.
I tried many patterns but none of them worked for both of them. If one gets matched then the other wont.

**Test Data:**

```
4400634848591837Cvv: 362Expm: 04Expy: 20
4400634848591837:04 20 362
4400634848591837|04/24 362
4400634848591837 0420 362
```

**Regex:**

```
(\d{16})[\/\s:|]*?(\d\d)[\/\s|]*?(\d{2,4})[\/\s|-]*?(\d{3})
```

This matches the rest of them but I haven't figured out how to match first line. I have tried `+-` Lookahead & Lookbehind but It never worked for me. So any help would be great.

**Demo:**  [Here](https://regex101.com/r/9Zg5cz/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part after the 16 digits for the first line has a different format, and the order of the values is also different.

You can use an alternation `|` with 3 groups to get the values vor the Cvv part.

Note that you don't have to make the character class `[\/\s|-]*?` non greedy using the `?` as the characters can not cross matching the digits that follow.

```
\b(\d{16})(?:[\/\s:|]*(\d\d)[\/\s|]*(\d{2,4})[\/\s|-]*(\d{3})|Cvv:\s*(\d{3})Expm:\s*(\d\d)Expy:\s*(\d\d))\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(\d{16})(?:[\/\s:|]*(\d\d)[\/\s|]*(\d{2,4})[\/\s|-]*(\d{3})` The pattern for the last 3 lines
- `|` Or
- `Cvv:\s*(\d{3})Expm:\s*(\d\d)Expy:\s*(\d\d))` The pattern for the first line, matching the texts in the line followed by capturing the digits in 3 groups
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C2o4Tk/1)